# Choosing definite ViewController from opened View stacks

Tags: objective-c

I have 5 UIs/Views and these are if in normal way,one after another..1->2->3->4->5..But when i reach page 5, I would like to reopen page 3 back.I know i can use PushViewController but this one is as creating one more view and I don't want to do like that.As my views are already in view stack i m wondering anything like i can choose the definite view from just now opened stacks.For PopViewController i can open very recent page (for my case it will be page 4).But i would like to jump over to page 3.How can I do that?Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically three ways you can go back in the `UINavigationController`'s stack:

1. One controller at a time, using [`popViewControllerAnimated:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popViewControllerAnimated:).
2. All the way back to the bottom of the stack, using [`popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToRootViewControllerAnimated:).
3. Back to a specific controller in the stack, using [`popToViewController:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToViewController:animated:).

That last should do what you're trying to do. The one down side is that you need to pass that method a pointer to controller you want to back track to. So you'll need to figure out some way to make that happen (pass a pointer down through the stack, walk back the chain of `parentViewController` values, keep a pointer at your application delegate, etc.).

Comment: Thanks.I will try as you said.I really appreciate ur answer.